# How to add a product according to the category in django with custom html template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to add products into django db by selecting categories. Its adding the product into db but the category shows its None so.
I don't know.

## views.py:

```
def addpro(request):

    cat = Category.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.POST.get('name')
        price = request.POST.get('price')
        stock = request.POST.get('stock')
        cate = request.POST.get('category')
        img = request.FILES['img']
        obj = FileSystemStorage()

        img2 = obj.save(img.name, img)

  
        if Product.objects.filter(name=name).exists():

            return redirect('add')
        else:
            
        
            Product.objects.create(name=name, price=price, stock=stock , image=img2 , categ = cate )

            return redirect('add')

    return render(request, 'Add.html',{'category':cat})
```

## models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30 , null = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Name)

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/',null =True)
    categ = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## This is block of code for select category. Everything fine but can't add product according categories

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Category</strong></label>
                <select name="categ" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                    {% for cat in category %}
                        <option id="category" selected="selected" value="{{ cat.id }}">{{cat.Name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the template? You should create ModelForm.

Comment: Your `Product` model has a FK to `Category`, but instead you are adding whatever comes from the `request.data`. Does the `request.POST.get('category')` holds an ID of `Category` instance?

Comment: In addition, all your models attributes must start with lowercase